# Newrelic integration with private node npm package

Tags: node.js, npm, newrelic, newrelic-platform

I have a private npm package(library) that I want to integrate with new relic. I do understand that integration of newrelic with an http application is straightforward. But for my use case, I want to integrate newrelic directly with a library for observability and I don't want to trace it by attaching to parent http application.

Comment: I am not sure that I understood your question. You have a node js application, but you want to monitor just a single package? Like, you want to monitor only part of your application? Are you trying to integrate the APM monitoring of New Relic, or the Browser Monitoring?

Comment: I have a private npm package, it is integrated with multiple HTTP services as node_module dependency, I can monitor it through the HTTP service it is tied with, but for my use-case I want to monitor it independently.